# MySQL/PHP: consolidate results such as footnotes from multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql, database

I've learned a lot from this forum, and thanks in advance.  Basically, I'm trying to do "footnotes" for results from a database query of multiple tables.  My table has the "bibliographic reference" for each of several bio materials, but I'm not able to consolidate the results in a way that is more readable.  I think I need to use multidimensional arrays, but I think there must be a more elegant way.  MySQL portion in php code is:

```
    $queryFromAgentBW = "SELECT DISTINCT reports.ID, reports.link, agent_names.ID, agent_names.Name, agent.BW_Actor_List, agent.Common_Name, agent.Reference, actor_list.ID

                         FROM agent_names, agent

                         JOIN actor_list ON(agent.BW_Actor_List = actor_list.ID) 

                         JOIN reports ON(agent.Reference = reports.ID)

                         WHERE  agent_names.ID = agent.Agent_Name AND BW_Actor_List = '".mysql_real_escape_string($a)."'";


 $resultFromAgentBW = mysql_query($queryFromAgentBW);

      //check result;  show error for debugging
      if (!$resultFromAgentBW)
      {
   $message = 'Invalid query:'.mysql_error()."\n";
   $message .= 'Whole query:'.$queryFromAgentBW;
  die($message);
      } 
     while ($rowBW = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultFromAgentBW))  
     {

//  Need to get all this in an array and then print out later so agents 
          are listed only once with  all of the corresponding reference numbers
$bwArray[] = $rowBW;


              }
```

And the php "pretty printing" portion of code is:

```
    foreach ($bwArray as $bw) 
    {     
echo "Name: {$bw['Name']}<br />"
. "Ref: {$bw['Reference']}<br />"
. "Link: {$bw['link']}<br /><br />";
     }
```

The result is now:

```
    Name: Abrin toxin
    Ref: 1
    Link: C:\wamp\www\References\Abrin\AbrinandRicin_Patocka.pdf

    Name: Abrin toxin
    Ref: 6
    Link: C:\wamp\www\References\Abrin\TheEmergencyResponseSafetyandHealthDatabase_           Biotoxin_ ABRIN.pdf

    Name: Adenovirus
    Ref: 9
    Link: C:\wamp\www\References\Adenovirus\Adenovirus (Serotypes 40 & 41)_PHAC .pdf


   Name: Adenovirus
   Ref: 13
   Link: C:\wamp\www\References\Adenovirus\AdenovirusSerotype31InfectioninaNewbornGirlandReviewoftheLiterature.pdf
```

but ideally it would be:

```
    Abrin Toxin   [1, 6]
    Adenovirus    [9, 13]
```

where the numbers are href links shown as text now (PDF document reference).   Thanks for any help or guidance on what would be best in this case!

Comment: this is not a forum, you know

Comment: Ashok learn OOP, then how to implement DAO. Then how to separate the view from the logic. That means in your case: do not do both in the same file: working with the database AND interleaving html.

Comment: @ Col. Shrapnel- Whoops!  Apologies, I should have said Q&A site!   @ Flavius - Yes, improving my OOP and DAO understanding will improve my overall skills and perhaps optimize the code, but the simple hint/guidance by Andrej L (which came BEFORE your comment) is all I needed and really answers the question. Also, your comment regarding wamp shows a provincial mindset or worse ignorance, when you have little context on why this was specifically chosen, or the background behind my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add **group_concat** function and **group by** clause to your query and make all work in mysql

```
SELECT group_concat(agent.Reference SEPARATOR ','), agent_names.ID, agent_names.Name

                     FROM agent_names, agent

                     JOIN actor_list ON(agent.BW_Actor_List = actor_list.ID) 

                     JOIN reports ON(agent.Reference = reports.ID)

                     WHERE  agent_names.ID = agent.Agent_Name AND BW_Actor_List =  '".mysql_real_escape_string($a)."'
GROUP BY agent_names.ID
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. You're right - it's cleaner and faster working in mysql.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to properly aggregate your results in an array. Change last two loops to:

```
while ($rowBW = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultFromAgentBW)) {
    $bwArray[$rowBW['Name']][] = $rowBW;
}
foreach ($bwArray as $name => $refs) {
    echo 'Name: ' . $name . ' [';
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($refs); $i++) {
        echo ($i > 0 ? ' ' : '') . '<a href="' . $ref['link'] . '">' . $ref['Reference'] . '</a>';
    }
    echo ']<br />';
}
```

I omitted data escaping with `htmlspecialchars()` for better readability.

Comment: Thanks - this helped me get the references to also link properly as I needed after incorporating the updated SELECT statement from Andrej.